# Programmatically Add link to Homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, hyperlink

The question is quite basic however I'm not able to find any "links" to it...

I want to customize Homepage, programmatically adding hyperlinks as you can "manually" do from "Edit" page.

How to access homepage using CSOM?
How adding new links?

Answer (score 1):

You could refer this demo using NavigationNodeCreationInformation class:

[Add/Update/Delete nodes from QuickLaunch (Current Navigation)/ Global Navigation using Client Side Object Model (CSOM) in SharePoint 2013 Online](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987078/Add-Update-Delete-nodes-from-QuickLaunch-Current-N)